# Terminal closes immediately after trying to change shell script back to bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I was playing around with fish shell on my Ubuntu but wanted to switch back to bash. I tried running

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

but that didn't work, I got some error, which IIRC was regarding permissions, so I tried doing

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash
```

That seemed to work and didn't show any errors. So I proceed to try logging out and logging back in to see the effects of this change. But from then on, every time I try opening the terminal, it would just immediately close.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the symlink in broken... Have a squiz here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25423/how-to-reinstall-bin-sh

Comment: What error you got while doing `chsh -s /bin/bash`?

Comment: I managed to solve it! Turns out it was an error with fish shell and it just crashed every time I tried opening the terminal. I have added my process in the question. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Zinthos Rather providing solution in question section,  you can post answer of your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself. Allow me to explain:

I went to virtual console with ctrl + alt + F1 then tried logging in there, but same issue happened, I was a quick message pop up and I was back to login stage in the virtual console. The message went by way too fast so but I managed to grab it my camera.

It turns out it was an error with fish shell: (not exactly sure if how I caused this error)

```
fish: relocation error: fish: symbol _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE7reserveEm, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

So this told me that fish shell was still my default shell script `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash` did not do the trick for me. I was able to further confirm this by checking `/etc/passwd` and saw that my user still has `/usr/bin/fish` and fish was broken somehow which caused the terminal to immediately close. Finally found the root of the problem!

I then proceed to edit my passwd file by running bash from grub as root following instructions from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282141/212011 where I simply find the line with my username and changed `/usr/bin/bash` back to `/bin/bash` and then it was all good again!